# How to query each element in the array in mongodb to return document where all the elements satisfy the condition

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which has booking as array of object with start date and end date .

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6053364dc406029c54025d01"),
    "id" : "b2f1ba33-3fd8-463a-8f12-6433b111bf6d",
    
    "name" : "Royal Hotel",
    
    "booking" : [
        {
            "startDate" : "2021-08-01",
            "endDate" : "2021-08-25"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6053364dc406029c54025d11"),
    "id" : "b2f1ba33-3fd8-463a-8f12-6433b111bf6f",
    
    "name" : "Paradise",
    
    "booking" : [
        {
            "startDate" : "2021-08-01",
            "endDate" : "2021-08-25"
        },
        {
            "startDate" : "2021-08-29",
            "endDate" : "2021-08-30"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to find those booking which are available for dates between 2021-08-27 to 2021-08-30 .

I have used below code which is working fine if there is just one element in the array but failing with the above data points

((2021-08-27 < booking.startDate && 2021-08-30 < booking.startDate) ||
(booking.endDate < 2021-08-30 && booking.endDate < 2021-08-27))

How can i query on each element in the array and return that document only if each element of the array satisfy the condition.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

- Try `$elemMatch` to match elements in array of object,
- match both dates with `$gte` and `$lte` in `$or` condition

```
db.collection.find({
  booking: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $or: [
        {
          startDate: {
            $gte: "2021-08-27",
            $lte: "2021-08-30"
          }
        },
        {
          endDate: {
            $gte: "2021-08-27",
            $lte: "2021-08-30"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/elXI7WaUwui)